# Is there a way to decorate the text within the Link element of 'react-router-dom'?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-router-dom

I added style properties to  to reset the text style between  element. 'style={{textDecoration='none'}

```js
function Navigation() {
    return (
        <div className="nav">
            <Link className='nav__btn' style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }} to='/'>Home</Link>
            <Link className='nav__btn' style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }} to="/about">About</Link>
        </div>);
}
```

And I wrote the code on the css as follows.

```css
.nav .nav__btn {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

.nav .nav__btn:hover{
    transform: scale(1.1);
    color: orange;
    text-decoration: underline;
    transition: transform .35s;
}
```

The font color changes when the mouse hovers, but  'text-decoration: underline' doesn't work.

I think there's a crash, but I don't know exactly what's wrong.
Is there any way to apply underline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inline CSS has higher priority than external CSS

[Priority of CSS Values For an HTML Document](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0d183d/priority-of-css-values-for-an-html-document/)

You are addind an inline CSS for text-decoration with:

```
style={{ textDecoration: 'none' }}
```

And then trying to overwrite it with your external CSS, but without effect because inline CSS has higher priority over external, and since the font color is not having any other CSS is taking the external CSS